# White Text on Black Screen, then a restart

Tags: windows-7

When I got out of the shower this morning, I came back upstairs to find my computer screen had changed from what I usually see to a black screen with a bunch of white text on it. I unfortunately did not catch what the text was, as it disappeared too quickly for me to get close enough and read it clearly. Once it was done with that, it restarted, and now things seem to be fine

Sorry for the lack of information, I only caught the last little bit of it before the restart. Has anyone else here had this problem?

System:

- Fujitsu LifeBook (Build: 23NIK--MS--1),  Windows 7 Home Premium w/
  Service Pack 1, 64-bit, Intel i5-3210m @ 2.5GHz, 6gb of RAM (not sure
  which type)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but without that info from the text, no one can tell you for sure what the cause of it was. But **most likely**, it was a "Recovering from an Error" screen, which happens when the computer does not shut down properly. Something like this:
[image]

As long as it doesn't keep coming up every time you turn on or restart your computer, you have nothing to worry about. (This screen can come up once or twice after you have a power flickering, or you unplug the computer while it is still running.)